# Send range via email with google script

Tags: google-apps-script, range, sendmail

I want to send range by email

For example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GH5r0sY_Z-15M479xG12yCUZaV0NRU8jpkWAxPNBuwU/edit?usp=sharing

I tried this:

```
function sendInvoiceList(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invoice").getRange("A1:B10").getValues();
  var message = sheet;
  var email_subj = "Invoice " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1:00", "dd.MM.yyyy");
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "user@gmail.com",
     subject: email_subj,
     htmlBody: "Please send us this list:<br><br><br>" + message
 });
}
```

The system send this: 
textA1,textA2,textA3,textA4,textA5,textA6,textA7,textA8,textA9,textA10

I need value in range A1:B10 but the system only A1 separated by comma I need in column format.

How do it? 
Thanks for support
Angelo

Comment: Try replacing the third line with: `var message = ' '.join(sheet)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setting message equal  to a two dimensional array you need to rethink that.  I think this maybe closer to what you want.  I tested it with some data of my own but don't know what you have.  Share an image of your spreadsheet if you need more assistance.

```
function sendInvoiceList(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  var rg=sh.getRange("A1:B10")
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>';
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    html+='<tr>';
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(i=0) {
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>',c)
      }else{
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',c)
      }
    });
    html+='</tr>';
  });
  html+='</table>';
  var email_subj = "Invoice " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1:00", "dd.MM.yyyy");
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: "user@gmail.com",subject: email_subj,htmlBody: "Please send us this list:<br><br><br>" + html});
 //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Display');//Just a dialog for testing the html
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper,
I tried your code and it works correctly!! I received a table with 2 columns.

Thank you for your support!

Angelo